# Issues with Batch based file/folder creation

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

First, I'd like to thank anyone who can help in advance, I haven't done any batch scripts like this in years and being 'rusty' is an understatement. I have a lot of files on a mapped drive that I want to do some work with without risking damage to those files so I'm trying to create a local version of 'fake' files so no harm if something gets screwed up.

This is all being done on a Windows 7 machine, so I started with running the following to get the entire directory listing to manipulate:

```
dir /b M:\ > movies.txt
```

From there, if I run the following, I'm able to get individual 0 byte fake files based on the lines inside 'movies.txt':

```
for /F "eol=; tokens=1* delims=," %%i in (movies.txt) do @echo.> %%i.avi
```

Or if I run the following, I'll get empty directories based on 'movies.txt':

```
for /F "delims=~" %%f in (movies.txt) DO MD "%%f"
```

The problem with either of these commands is that I either get a pile of files all lumped into the root folder (first 'for' command) or I get empty directories (second 'for' command) but I can't seem to figure out how to get the fake files into the folders.

Examples: If Mapped Drive "M" has these movie files:

```
M:\Las Vegas Trip (2009)\Las Vegas Trip (2009).avi
M:\Las Vegas Trip (2010)\Las Vegas Trip (2010).avi
```

then 'movies.txt' will appear as:

```
Las Vegas Trip (2009)
Las Vegas Trip (2010)
```

and the first command will result in:

```
D:\Las Vegas Trip (2009).avi
D:\Las Vegas Trip (2010).avi
```

or the second command will result in:

```
D:\Las Vegas Trip (2009)\
D:\Las Vegas Trip (2010)\
```

But what I need is:

```
D:\Las Vegas Trip (2009)\Las Vegas Trip (2009).avi
D:\Las Vegas Trip (2010)\Las Vegas Trip (2010).avi
```

I've been searching the internet for days and can't seem to find anything that will give me the desired results... I did find a slightly similar 'issue' elsewhere where they wanted to create the folders based on file name, but they wanted to auto-rename the end result filename which wont work. (Yes I tried to modify their command to work, but no changes I could come up with would produce anything but errors.)
You can see the above mentioned method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597132/batch-script-to-create-folders-based-on-filenames) (on site).

Modifications I attempted to the code from the link included:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir *.png /b') do md %%~nf & move %f .\%%~nf\0000.png <- original
for /f %%f in ('dir *.avi /b') do md %%~nf & move %f .\%%~nf\*.avi
for /f %%f in ('dir *.avi /b') do md %%~nf & move %f .\%%~nf\
for /f %%f in ('dir *.avi /b') do md %%~nf & move %f .\%%~nf
```

In each case I was given an error in reference to the final part of the code "%%~nf*.avi" section.

Any ideas of how to either modify that code to work for me or something else that would work would be greatly appreciated.

-------Edited Part-------
I tried changing my batch file to use the command provided in the post below and it didn't seem to work:

```
cd Movies2
dir /b %MovieSource% > movies.txt
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir *.avi /b') do md "%%~nf" & move "%~f" ".\%%~nf\*.avi"
rem for /F "eol=; tokens=1* delims=," %%i in (movies.txt) do @echo.> %%i.avi
rem FOR /F "delims=~" %%f in (movies.txt) DO MD "%%f"
```

I also tried putting the first 'for' command second and unREM'd the other 'for' command so that it would create the *.avi's beforehand, thinking that might work, but trying it either way gives the same error.

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~f" ".\%%~nf\*.avi"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET oldroot=M:\
SET newroot=D:\newroot\
FOR /R "%oldroot%" %%f IN (*) DO CALL :processfile "%%f"
GOTO :EOF

:processfile
SET "oldfile=%~1"
CALL SET "newfile=%%oldfile:%oldroot%=%newroot%%%"
CALL :checkpath "%newfile%"
ECHO.>"%newfile%"
GOTO :EOF

:checkpath
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
IF NOT EXIST "%~dp1" MKDIR "%~dp1"
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF
```

- This script iterates through all the files by the path specified in `oldroot`.
- The old root path in each fully qualified file name is replaced with the path to the new root (the `newroot` variable), resulting in another fully qualified file name (stored in the `newfile` variable).
- The new file's path is checked: if it does not exist, it is created.
- Finally, an empty file with the new name is generated.

**EDIT**

The `ECHO.>"%newfile%"` line actually produces a file with an EOL character (`0x0D0A`) in it, so the size of such a file is 2, not 0. If you wish it to be 0, you can replace the `ECHO` bit with this construct:

```
SET /P somevaryrandomandunusedvarname=>"%newfile%" <NUL
```

Comment: This solution worked great. The 2b over 0b is no problem, the only part I noticed is that it recreated a 2b dummy for every file including the meta files (which is what I want the dummies for to create) but it was simple to add a couple lines at the end to dig and delete the un-needed ones, so overall great success.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems to be the problem in the `FOR /F` statement, as it uses as standard delim `<space>` and `<TAB>`.

It should work with something like

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir *.avi /b') do md "%%~nf" & move "%~f" ".\%%~nf\*.avi"
```